# Total network waiting time for all http requests

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, single-page-application, web-performance, front-end-optimization

Not sure whether anybody has similar query here, assume we do a performance tracing on a single page application completely loaded on a url, how to get the total waiting time on networking time for all resources?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard about an existing tool that would provide the exact metric you're looking for. But you could write a mini script that uses the Resource Timing API. It is easy to list all network requests and sum up waiting times. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Resource_Timing_API/Using_the_Resource_Timing_API).

Then, if you need to automate measures, you can use Puppeteer to run your script on a headless Chrome.

Comment: thanks very much for the advice, Resource Timing API would help me on this, will look in to it.